# Add up 2 datagridview cell values

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 Datagridview controls in vb.net form. DGV1 with price column, DGV2 with quantity column and the 3rd one is the total column DGV3. deos anyone tell me please on how to do this, DGV1*DGV2 show the total on DGV3 and update DGV3 everytime DVG1 cellvalue get changed. my code below doesn't update DGV3. also, one of the problems is that DGV3 get calculated before DGV2 bind the DATA and if DGV2 cell value=0 it gives me a wrong total. any idea ? appreciated,

```
 Private Sub DGV1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV1.CellValueChanged
    Dim Tot As Int32 = 0
   DGV3.Enabled = False
    DGV3.DataSource = Nothing
    DGV3.Enabled = True

    Dim OBJ As Double
    Dim SALES As Integer
    Dim dtt As DataTable
    For Each R As DataGridViewRow In Me.DGV1.Rows
        For Each N As DataGridViewRow In Me.DGV2.Rows

            OBJ = CDbl(R.Cells(4).Value)
            SALES = CInt(CDbl(N.Cells(0).Value))
            Tot = CInt(OBJ * SALES)
            DGV3.Rows.Add(Tot.ToString)

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to have three Datagridview, could you not use one with three columns?

Comment: each datagrid is bind to a source file. i tried adding all columns to one datagrid with bindingsource.add(row), i got error "adding a row to bindingource must be the same type" i couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to use the one datagridview, I would go about it like this:

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ''// Set the number of columns.
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = True

        ''// Set the column header style. 
        Dim columnHeaderStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle()

        columnHeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige
        columnHeaderStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = columnHeaderStyle

        ''// Set column names.
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Price"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Quantity"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Total"

        DataGridView1.Enabled = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView1.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellChanged

        ''// show the total in column 3 and update column 3 everytime column `price's` cellvalue gets changed.
        If (DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0) Then
            ''// MsgBox("Updating column three `Total`")

            For Each R As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                On Error Resume Next ''// iKNOW <-.->

                Dim price As Double = R.Cells(0).Value.ToString
                Dim quantity As Integer = R.Cells(1).Value.ToString

                ''// not the auto new new at the bottom. <`.'>
                If Not (R.IsNewRow) Then
                    Dim Tot As Double = CInt(price * quantity)
                    R.Cells(2).Value = Tot
                End If

            Next

        End If

     End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. but how would you add all datatables from DGV1 and DGV2 to DGV3 bindingsource if I have to use only one DGV ? as I said, I have tried it and I got error "adding a row to bindingource must be the same type"

Comment: error "Objects added to a BindingSource's list must all be of the same type."

Answer (score 0):

Create an Empty DGV and Add the desired columns in it using Add Columns. Then use Edit Columns to select the values to be displayed under each specific column which you have created now. You could see DataBindingsource option in every newly created column. so choose your needed Datasource to be binded and the DisplayMember (the column name that contains values that you like to display)